# Pixel intensity of RGB images and how to multiply it with integers to view shades of gray

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an RGB image that has 4 distinct colors Black(0,0,0) as background, Green(106,136,93) Blue(64,224,208) & Brown(168,124,85). when I read the image as a grayscale and use np.unique() it returns a huge list of pixel intensities.
But in reality, there are just 4 intensities i.e[0,1,2,3] Black, Green, Blue & Brown.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

test = cv2.imread("test-BlackBG.png",0) #test image 

results = np.unique(test)     #returns [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...........132]
print(test.shape)             #returns (480, 640)
print(results)
cv2.imshow("image",test)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Expected Result: when I multiply the image with 85, it should show me all the 3 intensities in different shades of gray.

[image: This is the Input image-"test-BlackBG.png", Stackoverflow wont let me post an image in the question maybe because I'm new to it.]

Comment: Are you trying to ultimately trying to achieve a grayscale image? If so try `gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: If the image you have included in your question is the starting image, you should be aware that it has 790 unique colours in it...

Comment: Maybe start another question about the way you create this image... has it been saved as a JPEG at some stage in its life? Why does it have an unused alpha channel?

Comment: That seems very unlikely. Did you count the number of greys with `np.unique()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your question and assumptions.

---

## You cannot count colours with `np.unique(image)`

You cannot count the colours in an image with `np.unique(im)`. Let's see why by making a random image with just 4 intensities: 0,1,2 and 3.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Ensure repeatable, deterministic randomness!
np.random.seed(42)

# Make a random image
im = np.random.randint(0,4,(480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

That looks like this where each row is the RGB triplet for one pixel:

```
array([[[2, 2, 3],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [2, 2, 0],
    ...,
    [3, 3, 2],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]],
    ...,
    [3, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [0, 1, 3]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Now, if you try and get the unique colours like this, it will not work, because each colour is a **combination** of 3 intensities:

```
np.unique(im)    # prints: array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8)
```

Whereas, if you want the number of unique colours, you need to look for the number of unique combinations of three RGB/BGR values:

```
np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0)
```

which gives a vector of the unique RGB/BGR triplets in the image - each row is a unique colour combination:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [0, 3, 3],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 0],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 2],
       [3, 0, 3],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [3, 3, 1],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

Or, as a simple number of unique colours:

```
len(np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0))    # prints 64
```

So, for your image:

```
# Open image
im = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Count unique colours
len(np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0)    # prints 790
```

---

## There are more colours than you expect

Why do I have more colours than I expect? The two most common reasons are:

- the image was saved as a JPEG
- there is text or drawn shapes that were anti-aliased

Let's look at how saving as a JPEG messes you up!

```
# Load image and count colours
im = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
len(np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0))    # prints 790

# Save as JPEG
cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg',im)

# Reload and recount just the same
im = cv2.imread('temp.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
len(np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0))    # prints 4666 !!!
```

---

## How can I palettise an image - (reduce colours to a fixed palette)?

If you want to palettise your image to your own specific palette, firstly you need to specify your palette in BGR order (`!`) to match OpenCV's ordering:

```
palette = np.array([
   [0,0,0],                # Black
   [93,136,106],           # Green
   [208,224,64],           # Blue
   [85,124,168]],          # Brown
   dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then read your image discarding the completely pointless alpha channel:

```
test = cv2.imread("image.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Then calculate the distance to each palette entry from each pixel:

```
distance = np.linalg.norm(test[:,:,None] - palette[None,None,:], axis=3)
```

Then choose whichever one of the palette colours is nearest for each pixel:

```
palettised = np.argmin(distance, axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
```

Your image is now in the array `palettised` and stored at each pixel location is the index of the nearest colour in your palette - so, as your palette has 4 entries (0..3), all elements of your image are 0, 1, 2 or 3.

So, now you can multiply by 85 with:

```
result = palettised * 85
```

[image]

Comment: You got me the result, but I had a different approach towards it. I used cv2.inrange() to swap green with rgb(1,1,1), brown with rgb(2,2,2) and blue with rgb(3,3,3). This gave me a black image and when I multiplied it with 85, I got a similar image as your output.  I love your solution and would try it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the edges are throwing it off. Try writing a function to set the pixels that make up the edges of your shapes into the exact color of that shape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking for here but to determine the RGB pixel intensity of images, you can isolate each `R`, `G`, and `B` channel while setting the other channels to 0.

Original image

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('pikachu_smile.png')

blue = image.copy()
# Set green and red channels to 0
blue[:, :, 1] = 0
blue[:, :, 2] = 0

green = image.copy() 
# Set blue and red channels to 0
green[:, :, 0] = 0
green[:, :, 2] = 0

red = image.copy()
# Set blue and green channels to 0
red[:, :, 0] = 0
red[:, :, 1] = 0

cv2.imshow('blue', blue)
cv2.imshow('green', green)
cv2.imshow('red', red)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Isolated blue (left), green (middle), and red (right) channels

[image]
[image]
[image]

To increase the intensity of a specific channel, you can add a fixed value to the entire channel. For example, with the green channel

```
green[:, :, 1] += 40
```

[image]