# How to get set of colours in an image using python PIL

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

After importing an image using python's PIL module I would like to get the set of colours in the image as a list of rgb tuples.

What If I know before hand that there will only be 2 colours and the image will be very small, maybe 20x20 pixels? However, I will be running this algorithm over a lot of images. Will It be more effiient to loop through all pixels until I see 2 unique colours? Because I understand loops are very slow in python.

Comment: What file format are the images stored in? And can you share a couple of images, or links to them, please?

Comment: I will be working on images as they come in, they could be png or jpg. It could be a screenshot over some text, with the top left and bottom right coordinates over a single letter. Then running my algorithm over the coordinates of that single letter would give me a list of 2 tuples representing the colour of the background and the text.

Comment: If your images are of text, which is normally anti-aliased, or in JPEG format, it is almost certain they will not actually only contain 2 unique colours. You will probably need to do a colour quantisation, or a k-means clustering to get sensible values. Try looking at on of your images enormously enlarged around the edges of the letters to see what I mean.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here to get started... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576159/2836621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's make an image. I'll just use **ImageMagick** to make a blue background with magenta writing:

```
convert -size 300x120 -background blue -fill magenta -gravity center -font AppleChancery label:"StackOverflow" PNG24:image.png
```

[image]

As you can see, I only specified two colours - magenta and blue, but the PNG image actually contains 200+ colours and the JPEG image contains 2,370 different colours!

So, if I want to get the two main colours, I can do this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image
im = Image.open('image.png') 

# Quantize down to 2 colour palettised image using *"Fast Octree"* method:
q = im.quantize(colors=2,method=2)

# Now look at the first 2 colours, each 3 RGB entries in the palette:
print(q.getpalette()[:6])
```

**Sample Result**

```
[0, 0, 255, 247, 0, 255]
```

If you write that out as 2 RGB triplets, you get:

```
RGB 0/0/255   = blue
RGB 247/0/255 = magenta
```

The best way to do this for lots of images is to use multithreading or multiprocessing if you want them done fast!

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to automatically annotate the RGB values in Python to a basic set of colors, so (0,0,255) would be labeled as blue in Python?